# Intercept Firebase SDK/Angular Fire calls in Angular

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angular13

Does anyone know is it possible to intercept the requests made to firebase authentication with AngularFire v7 library ?

Use case:
My application has phone authentication. Whenever user is logged in, and some admin disables the user account from the Firebase console. Whenever user reloads the app, the auth object is recieved null and an Error response is received from this API:
*POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=AIzaSyAiPctyxsb1rWPqI-VqwhXmha1_1GwO4t4 400* (response contains error code and message that i need)

**What i want is to be able to catch this error and show some kind of snackbar to user that they are logged out due to account disabled by admin**

How can I intercept the requests made from AngularFirestore library ?

I am using @angular/fire 7.2 and angular 13 and firebase@10

Thanks, Prateek

I have tried adding catchError to all auth object, authState, etc. nothing works.